# Best practice to update database during an event flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using imagemin to compress files as they are being uploaded to our NodeJS server. The logic below is a short snippet to explain what is happening. All this works but I'm trying to figure out a more efficient way/best practice to make this more elegant.

What I'm looking for is a way to call only the TaskModel query once and when imagemin.run is complete to update the database with the generated base64Images. Playing with some async tasks but would like to get the basics first!

Imagemin Link: https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin

```
var fileList = [].concat(req.files.userFile);
        for (var x = 0; x < fileList.length; x++) {
            var fileItem = fileList[x];

            var imagemin = new Imagemin()
                .src(fileItem.path)
                .use(Imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}))
                .use(Imagemin.pngquant());

            imagemin.run(function (err, files) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error on optmization!' + err);
                }

                files.forEach(function (tmpFile) {
                    var base64Image = new Buffer(tmpFile.contents).toString('base64');
                    TaskModel.findById(taskId, function (err, tmpTask) {
                        tmpTask.imgs.push({
                            bin: base64Image
                        })

                        tmpTask.save(function (err) {
                            if (!err) {
                               console.log("Image compressed and task updated");
                            } else {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                    })
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the async library: https://github.com/caolan/async

```js
var fileList = [].concat(req.files.userFile);
var minified = [];
async.each(fileList, function(fileItem, done){
    var imagemin = new Imagemin()
                .src(fileItem.path)
                .use(Imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}))
                .use(Imagemin.pngquant());

    imagemin.run(function (err, files) {
        if(err){
            console.log('Error on optmization!' + err);
            return done(err);
        }
        if(files && files.length){
            minified.push(files[0]);
        }               
        done();
    });
}, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('error during minfication', err)
        return next(err); //assumes you're using express with a next parameter      
    }
    TaskModel.findById(taskId, function (err, tmpTask) {
        if(err){
            console.log('unknown taxk', err);
            return next(err);
        }
        for (var x = 0; x < minified.length; x++) {
            var f = minified[x]
            var base64Image = new Buffer(f.contents).toString('base64');
            tmpTask.imgs.push({bin:base64Image});
        }
        tmpTask.save(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
               console.log("Image compressed and task updated");
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                return next(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```